# How can I access the index of a Jinja2 loop inside a Python expression with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a small Flask website to display data as a table. The data is formatted as a list of dictionaries, and I'd like to display them in order in an HTML table.

My Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

dummy_data = [{"name": "Homer", "age": 40}, {"name": "Bart", "age": 12}, ...]

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", data=dummy_data)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      {% for person in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ data({{ loop.index }})["name"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data({{ loop.index }})["age"]}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This produces the error message:

```
redacted@robotron-ubuntu:/media/redacted/redacted/redacted/issuerep$ flask --app app run
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2023-03-11 22:01:26,498] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/media/redacted/redacted/redacted/issuerep/app.py", line 8, in index
    return render_template("app.html", data=dummy_data)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 146, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1067, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 996, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 957, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 137, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 756, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/home/redacted/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 924, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/media/redacted/redacted/redacted/issuerep/templates/app.html", line 12, in <module>
    <td>{{ data({{ loop.index }})["name"]}}</td>
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Seemingly I can't use the list index in a {{}} block because the Python expression is already in one. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. A Jinja expression starts and ends with double curly braces. You don't need this again to access the index of the iteration. You are already inside the expression.

However, since the index of a list starts at 0, the use of `loop.index0` is necessary.
Furthermore, you should recheck your syntax for accessing the element of the list using the index. You are using the wrong characters for this.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    {% for person in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ data[loop.index0]["name"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data[loop.index0]["age"]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

In general, the question arises as to why, in an iteration that supplies you with the current item, you still want to access this using the index. The simplest solution would be the following.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    {% for person in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```